# Impossibile to add NPOI library to dotnet core 1.1 library

Tags: c#, .net-core, npoi

I'm trying to add NPOI to a dotnet core library targeting netcoreapp1.1.
I'm able to add to the project, but if I add this line of code

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

I have this error message

```
Reference to type 'FileInfo' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
```

these are the packages added to the project

```
Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility Version="1.0.2" 
NPOI Version="2.3.0" 
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter Version="4.3.0"
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Open object browser (Ctrl+Alt+J) and check if mscorlib stay there. Also try to clean up your project.

Comment: with dotnet core I have no mscorlib

Comment: @PILHA indeed in .NET Core there is no reference to mscorlib and most of the types aren't defined in mscorlib, which .NET Framework assemblies would expect them to be defined in.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a library that was built for .NET Framework is loaded on .NET Core < 2.0.

.NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 can only load libraries that were built for .NET Standard (<= 1.6) or .NET Core (respective versions).

.NET Core 2.0 (in preview at time of writing) will have type forwarding assemblies that make a lot of .NET Framework assemblies work, but does not guarantee that all libraries will work unchanged.

Comment: I previously added the list of packages, but SO was hiding them thinking were html tags. Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility and System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter helps to fix this kind of problems. I was looking for some other package to fix this problem

Comment: the portable compatibility library enables a few PCL profiles for .net core, but there is no package that enables all .NET Framework code. I suggest you try the .NET Core 2.0 preview and see if that helps. It has a mscorlib.dll with a lot of type forwarders.